# Live Reload doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular, vagrant, ember-cli, angular-cli

I watched a few videos where the app was recompiled after any changes in the code were detected. Actually, when you run `ng serve` I think it should show something like

> Live reload server on ...

But for some reason it doesn't work in my case, so in order to see changes in code I have to close `ng serve` and run it again.

I have two default ports forwared in my Vagrantfile, one for web server and one for LiveReload server:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4200, host: 4200
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 49152, host: 49152
```

And, of course I have to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` to make this thing available from my host machine browser.

Comment: How are you using angular-cli and vagrant together?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu and this solve my problems:

```
sudo echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

I don't know are you using linux or not?

If above doesn't help you try to:

1. remove node_modules/
2. npm cache clean
3. npm install

Comment: Yes, I have Ubunru installed on my VM. But unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: When you made change you got message in console 'Nothing changed'

Answer (score 0):

I use angular-cli and the command that I use is `npm run start`. If you are using vagrant then I wonder how it would access your local browser. However, angular-cli doesn't really need vagrant to run, it generates it's own environment.

Comment: I use vagrant because I have Windows installed on my host machine and using linux for web development seems more comfortable to me.